# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using python and selenium to scrape a website full of text files (as URL's), and then using requests to get those txt files.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
r = requests.get(link,cookies=cookies)

    # Checking for a successful connection to the server.
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print("Downloading data for time %d, altitude %d" %(counter1, altitude) ) 
        data = r.text # Extracting the text from the file online
        file_name = os.path.join(path,fileName)  
        with open(file_name, 'w') as w:
            w.write(data)
        w.closed


    # Closing browser
    browser.close()
```

There are about 900 odd files to be downloaded, but after every 250 odd downloads/reqests, the script terminates with an error

OSError. [Errno 24] Too many files open.

I've made sure the the file that was being written to is closed. Same goes for selenium, after each text file is downloaded, the chromedriver closes, and the loop moves onto the next URL. Has anyone else encountered this, if so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Can you please post complete traceback, which would include which line the error is thrown from?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is there a reason you're not using wget?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: There is no traceback, it's an error thrown by the system I think, not python.

Comment: @PhilCairns The resultant text file is obtained after filling a form on the website followed by clicking a button (Update Data). Hence wget will not work, hence selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions.

I just realized that browser.close() closes the window but does not quit the instance of chromedriver. Since the initilization of the chromedriver was within the loop of extracting the data file, the script kept opening new instances of chromedriver, eventually overloading my memory with over 200 instances.

The simple fix to this is use webdriver.quit(), which will completely quit the instance of the webdriver.

Better still, instead of creating a new instance at the beginning of every loop iteration, at the end of the loop just use webdriver.get(URL), which will redirect the current instance to the target URL.

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but Python modules like ``robobrowser`` (basically imitator's of Ruby's ``mechanize`` can fill forms, and they're way faster and less problem-prone than ``selenium``. ``Selenium`` is really only necessary when the site has JavaScript that modifies the DOM in place (i.e. the OuterHTML, as opposed to the source HTML).